# Need to set a max results limit on KnP Paginator?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

Like the title says, I'm trying to implement a limit on the results available to be paginated by the KnP Paginator. Setting a limit on my query does nothing, I assume because the paginator sets it's own limit on the query to show the right number of rows per page.

My use case is fairly simple: user applies a few filters in the UI (field must equal X, order by, etc.) and the code translates those to inputs to the query builder. The limit is to allow the user to say 'show me the top 100 entries where [insert condition] is true, ordered by [field]'. Currently does not seem possible with KnP Paginator unless I'm missing something in the documentation.

Comment: Did you discover third parameter of `paginate` method of `knp_paginator` service?

Comment: Most definitely already have that in use. What I am looking for is a way to limit the larger data set and then paginate that. In otherwords, a way to tell the paginator I only want to show 500 results, but still give me 20 per page up to 500.

From what I can tell this isn't currently possible so I have implemented a UI workaround to stop showing results after I reach the desired limit.

Comment: Use custom `count` query: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/manual_counting.md

Answer (score 1):

Use custom `count` query:

```
<?php
$count = 500;

$query = $entityManager
    ->createQuery('SELECT a FROM AcmeMainBundle:Article a')
    ->setHint('knp_paginator.count', $count)
;
$pagination = $paginator->paginate($query, $page, 10);
```

Comment: So this seems to almost work. Adding the count hint as you describe limits the total number of pages available, but for example I set it to 25 with 20 per page, and expected to see 5 results on page=2, however I got all 20 results on that second page. Any idea why that might be?